# populating tableview cell with Parse class data

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a function that is called from the viewDidLoad method

```
func loadData()
{
    eventsData.removeAllObjects()

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Events")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    self.eventsData.addObject(object)
                }
                println("The Events data has \(self.eventsData.count) scores.")
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
```

this populates the eventsData NSMutableArray Successfully with 3 PFObjects.

However this is producing 0 rows

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    println("!!!!!!!!!The Events data has \(self.eventsData.count) scores.!!!!!")
    return self.eventsData.count

}
```

so with the help of the println It showed:
!!!!!!!!!The Events data has 0 scores.!!!!!
Successfully retrieved 3 scores.
The Events data has 3 scores.

so i figured out that the problem was that it initialises 0 tableview rows before the array is filled, thats why the table view isn't showing any data, however I looked for a solution to this but couldn't found any, Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an IBOutlet for your UITableView if you don't have already have one, then reload it's data

```
if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
            for object in objects {
                self.eventsData.addObject(object)
            }
            // Reload table here
            println("The Events data has \(self.eventsData.count) scores.")
        }
```

Comment: I had an IBOutlet for my UITableView but I didn't know about the reloading,  that solved it, thank you!!